# How to print the parse tree of Stanford JavaNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to get all the noun phrases using the `edu.stanford.nlp.*` package. I got all the subtrees of label value "NP", but I am not able to get the normal original `String` format (not Penn Tree format).

E.g. for the `subtree.toString()` gives `(NP (ND all)(NSS times)))` but I want the string "all times". Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: stanford tregex is useful for this kind of sentence. Its shows us tree structure for parsed lines. here is the link for stanford tregex http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tregex.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is something like:

```
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for ( final Tree t : tree.getLeaves() ) {
     sb.append(t.toString()).append(" ");
}
```

While I'm not 100% sure, I seem to recall this being the solution used for some software I worked on a few years back.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using the yield() method for the subtree, instead of creating a separate StringBuilder objext.

```
if (subtree.label().value().equals("NP")) {
    out.println(subtree);       //print subtree
    out.println(Sentence.listToString(subtree.yield()));    //print phrase  
    break;
}
```