# How to print a part of the dependencies graph

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I would like to print subtrees of a dependency graph. Specifically for the sentence "`I turn the red meat`" and the starting word `meat-NN`, the output should be: "`the red meat`".

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
protected String printSubGraph(IndexedWord startingWord, SemanticGraph graph) {
    Iterable<SemanticGraphEdge> outiter = graph.outgoingEdgeIterable(startingWord);

    // set the default bounds to the startingWord 
    int start = startingWord.beginPosition();
    int end = startingWord.endPosition();

    // search the next level for larger bounds
    // assume that everything in between the bounds belongs to the sub-graph of the startingWord
    for (SemanticGraphEdge edge : outiter) {
        start = Math.min(start, edge.getGovernor().beginPosition());
        start = Math.min(start, edge.getDependent().beginPosition());
        end = Math.max(end, edge.getGovernor().endPosition());
        end = Math.max(end, edge.getDependent().endPosition());
    }

    return graph.toRecoveredSentenceString().substring(start, end);
}
```

This is bad for three reasons:

1. I assume that everything in between the tokens belongs to starting word's subtree.
2. I do not search the whole subtree for larger bounds.
3. I assume that the graph is the whole text and the bounds are valid for the RecoveredSentenceString. (Which is not true, if the original text contains more than one sentence.)

Is there a way to get this subtree (and only this subtree) from a SemanticGraph or a CoreMap without implementing DFS myself? I'm aware of [the other way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148890/how-to-print-the-parse-tree-of-stanford-javanlp), but I don't know any means to locate an IndexedWord inside a Tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is not a dependency parse but a phrase structure parse.

Your sentence is :

> I turn the red meat.

The phrase structure parse of which is:

> (ROOT
>    (S
>      (NP (PRP I))
>      (VP (VBP turn)
>        (NP (DT the) (JJ red) (NN meat)))
>      (. .)))

You can write a [TregexPattern](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern.html) of the form :

> NP< (NN < meat)

to get the desired subtree or simply

> NP

to get all noun phrases.